# The usage of at the back/front side

Tags: word-usage

Is it wrong to say

> He is sitting at the backside of the classroom

or

> The desk is at the front side of the class .

When can we use **at the backside** and **at the front side**?!
What about these two sentences? Are they wrong?!

> He is sitting on the left side of me

If yes, how can I use **on the left side** and **on the right side** in a sentence?
I'd really appreciate it if you help me with these sentences because it's been a long time I've been thinking about them but I couldn't find any suitable answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, *'backside'* is *mostly* used to describe someone's buttocks! Also, 'back' and 'front' depending on contexts refer to sides only. You don't need to add the word 'side' as it would be redundant.

So, **context** matters. In all of your examples, it is clear that you are talking about the direction, side, or position. Here you go...

> sitting in the back of the classroom 
>  he is sitting on my left

---

Being a doctor I can say that I have often heard 'side' word being used to show the location of some discomfort or pain.

> pain is in the left side of my stomach

[Good information is here.](http://www.confusing-words.com/?toload=inner.Body_ConfusingWords&id=3973&BereichID=134&title=%20%3Ca%20href%3D%3F%3EConfusing%20Words%3C%2Fa%3E%20%3E%20&title2=back%20and%20backside)